# NotImplementedError: ElasticNetworkInterfaces(AmazonVPC).describe_network_interface_attribute is not yet implemented

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, mocking, boto3, moto

How describe a network interface attribute for a mock_ec2 in test_elastic_network_interfaces_get_by_description function?

```
@mock_ec2 def test_elastic_network_interfaces_get_by_description():
    ec2 = boto3.resource("ec2", region_name="us-east-1")
    ec2_client= ec2.meta.client

    vpc = ec2.create_vpc(CidrBlock="10.0.0.0/16")
    vpc.reload()
    subnet = ec2.create_subnet(
        VpcId=vpc.id, CidrBlock="10.0.0.0/24", 
        AvailabilityZone="us-east-1a")

    desc = str(uuid4())
    eni1 = ec2.create_network_interface(
        SubnetId=subnet.id, PrivateIpAddress="10.0.10.5", Description=desc )

    # The status of the new interface should be 'available'
    waiter = ec2_client.get_waiter("network_interface_available")
    waiter.wait(NetworkInterfaceIds=[eni1.id])

    eni1.modify_attribute(SourceDestCheck={'Value': False})
    eni1.reload()
    response = eni1.describe_attribute(Attribute='description')
```

python           3.7
mock            4.0.3
moto            2.1.0
sure            2.0.0
aiobotocore     1.4.2
boto3          1.18.2
botocore     ​1.20.106
coverage        5.5

[image: Image breakpoint debug in errorline]

What is needed to implement or fix to run or pass the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If after update or scaffold-script of moto library the method is not implemented in a library yet and continue an error like this :

> NotImplementedError:
> ElasticNetworkInterfaces(AmazonVPC).describe_network_interface_attribute
> is not yet implemented

An easy solution for the test is a monkeypatch function that lets simulates the method not implemented.

> ```
> def client_mock(Attribute='description'):
>     return {
>         'Attachment': {
>             'AttachTime': 34545,
>             'DeleteOnTermination': False,
>             'DeviceIndex': 123,
>             'NetworkCardIndex': 123,
>             'InstanceId': 'eni1.instanceid',
>         },
>         'Description': {
>             'Value': 'Vpc network inteface'
>         },
>         'Groups': [
>             {
>                 'GroupName': 'name group',
>                 'GroupId': 'grupoid'
>             },
>         ],
>         'NetworkInterfaceId': 'eni.id',
>         'SourceDestCheck': {
>             'Value': False
>         }
>     }
> ```

and put it with attributes on the pass at respective the function or method

```
monkeypatch.setattr(eni1, "describe_attribute", client_mock)
```

[image: Solution with monkeypatch]

If you know a better solution, please post it!

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to implement this feature in Moto, the documentation should help here: http://docs.getmoto.org/en/latest/docs/contributing/new_feature.html

TLDR:

There is a script that will generate the scaffolding for a new feature.

- Check out the Moto source code
- Install the project (`make init`)
- Run the scaffold-script: `scripts/scaffold.py`

It's always possible to open an issue, or create a draft PR in Moto - they are happy to help out if you want to contribute.
https://github.com/spulec/moto